# How to get my W2003-server (back) into the web (after setting up bridged networking)

Tags: virtualbox, windows-server-2003, bridge, windows-networking

I have recently set up Virtualbox on a W2003-Server (which is also used as webserver, accessed from the web). My vbox worked nicely, but then I wanted more, I wanted to have the vm appear in the intranet like any ordinary pc. I was advised to setup bridged networking as opposed to NAT. I did so, and in the server's network connections have bridged the LAN-Connection and the "VirtualBox Host-Only Network" (yes, it says "host only network", but I assure that VBox networking is configured to use network bridge).

So now my VM is visible in the intranet and it also has www-accesss, the server can also access the web. The only problem that came up is that the server is no longer accessible from the web. I've traced an HTTP-Request and it says "Can't connect to ***:80 (connect: No route to host)".

So maybe something in the router's config needs to be adjusted (yeah, well, the server's IP-Address changed from 192.168.1.199 to ...198). So I went into the router-config, reviewed port-forwarding for port 80 and adjusted the IP there, but it still didn't work.

Unsure if it was a router-problem or rather something in the server's config, I've setup a "demilitarized zone" in the router and have put the server into it. (My understanding is that this would put the server straight into the web...)   But the result of the HTTP-Requests is still the same :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had a technician here and it seems the router is going crazy - he's not forwarding port 80, although he's configured to do so. Changing to a different port which is then mapped to 80 of your server works.

Case closed, sorry for the disappointing solution "technical failure" :(

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer (you might have to wait a bit though). This will stop the Community user prodding the question back to the front page at a later date.